# Series diode voltage clipper, on Multisim clipping and shifting on positive and negative voltage

Tags: diodes, oscilloscope, series, multisim, voltage-clipping

This is my circuit:

[image]

I’m testing a Series diode clipper circuit, and the end result should be this:
(I've used 5V in my circuit, not 10V like in this plot, but this is not the issue)

[image]

Instead what I get in Multisim 11 is not what I was expecting.

These are the results on Multisim scope: 
(the green trace has been shifted 0.2V for visibility)
[image]

Please explain :

- Why the first three positive periods/peaks are shifted up and not
  down by 0.7V (forward voltage drop)?
- Why the cycles after the first three have a negative clipper in the
  negative phase and the positive peaks are shifted down?

These are the scope results, with dc reading:
(all the periods have now the same amplitude but still the positive peaks are above the 5V division, why?)
[image]

Comment: What result to you get when you set your scope inputs as DC-coupled instead of AC?

Comment: @brhans I've posted the scope with the DC reading, now all the periods have the same amplitude but the positive peaks are still above 5V. BTW, why did switching fron AC to DC fixed it partially? Shouldn't be the reading on AC, since I'm dealing with ac voltage?

Comment: @Luther, do you understand what Vrms means?

Comment: @DanLaks If Vrms will enlight me, I guess I'll study this topic.

Comment: @Luther, it will answer your question of why the voltage peaks are above 5V.

Comment: About AC/DC: Usually, you want the DC setting, as it always shows the actual voltage level. If you want to inspect a 10mV signal, you may choose the 5mV/Div setting, but the maximum voltage range will be -20...20mV or so. So, if you have 10V with a 10mV ripple on it, you can not inspect the ripple. Then, the AC mode can be used. It blocks the 10V and allows to see the 10mV ripple.